# Installing ROS for using with NAO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

Which packages do I need to install to work with Nao Robot?! 
I followed these 2 links from ROS Wiki, and I am really confused now :(  :

1. /nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started
2. /nao/Installation/remote

   The purpose of my project is that I need to detect some shapes and those colors to move them...

   Kind Regards,
   Nima

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119256/installing-ros-for-using-with-nao/) by [Nimaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9336/nimaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, you need to make sure you are using a supported operating system.  Typically if you're using Ubuntu you'll be fine.  The other systems are experimental and I cannot speak to how well they work (someone else want to chip in about that?)  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation

You then have to install a version of ROS.  My suggestion would be Hydro (newest) or Groovy(second newest). http://wiki.ros.org/hydro http://wiki.ros.org/groovy

I would read the first two things listed in the tutorials here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials  They should give you a little more background.

Edit: I forgot to add in this! http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/StartGuide I found reading the Start Guide immensely helpful because you really get a better understanding for how the structure behind this all works.

Once you're comfortable, then you can start looking into getting the Nao packages.

Edit2: http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Nao

One thing you'll learn about here is that no one will bother to teach you about something that you can easily find on the help pages.  I would ask more specific questions about specific roadblocks you encounter once you're more familiar with ROS.

Best of luck!

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nimaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9336/nimaa/) on 2014-01-20**:
Thanks for your Kind Responses man, yes I am using Ubuntu 12.04, I am gonna follow the tutorials here as you mentioned, the purpose is solving 3 pieces tower of Hanoi , I wish I could do this finally...

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-21**:
That sounds like an awesome project.  Just a heads up, ROS has a steep learning curve and you usually need to troubleshoot so I wouldn't assume you can just simply download everything and have it working perfectly right away.  If you're familiar with Linux already it will be easier though.

**Comment by [Nimaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9336/nimaa/) on 2014-01-21**:
I really don know what to say with these great support & answers here, Thank you a lot, before I came here, I was really hopeless working with ROS but now, I am ready to go ahead with that ... ;)